# Using two loops in wodrpess on same page: first should be 'built in' for static page, second should be with custom arguments

Tags: wordpress, loops, templates

I have pages with simple loop. It just displays content of the static page. 
However, at the bottom of some pages I need to add `second loop` that will find all posts from certain `category`. When I add second loop my page gets blank - neither first, nor second loop works. I am new to wordpress developing, thus I am missing something.

Here is the simplified code on my `page.php`:

```
<?php

// First loop - 'auto' loop. It should just show given page content.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
endwhile; // End of the loop.

// Second loop - it would contain custom arguments
$category_id = get_categor_for_page(get_the_ID());
if (isset($category_id)) {
    $post_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category_id, 'post_type' => 'post');
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
        // show posts from given category in carousel; for now just show in a list
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'post' );
    endwhile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add close bracket ) in new WP_Query and $post_query->the_post() instead of $my_query->the_post()

```
  <?php

    // First loop - 'auto' loop. It should just show given page content.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
    endwhile; // End of the loop.

    // Second loop - it would contain custom arguments
    $category_id = get_categor_for_page(get_the_ID());
    if (isset($category_id)) {
        $post_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category_id, 'post_type' => 'post'));
        while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post();
            // show posts from given category in carousel; for now just show in a list
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'post' );
        endwhile;
    }
```

Comment: Ohh, I have just found it by myself. Really stupid thing... If I would worked with two loops before I would know that it should be something easy. Instead, I thought I am missing something.

Comment: Its ok. you need category id to proceed